# Constructing cons list from slices

Tags: rust, linked-list, borrow-checker

Reading the book, I was trying to add methods to the "cons-list" type, defined as

```
enum List<T> {
   Item(T, Box<List<T>>),
   Null,
}
```

The first method I tried to implement was `from_slice` which build a cons list from `&[T]`.
However the borrow-checker does not accept the following implementation

```
impl<T> List<T> {
    
    pub fn from_slice(v: &[T]) -> List<T> 
    where T: Copy 
    {
        let n = v.len();

        let lst = List::Null;

        for i in (0..n).rev() {
            let lst = List::Item(v[i], Box::new(lst));
        }

        lst
    }
}
```

Why is this not accepted and what should I do to convince the borrow checker that this program is safe?

Interestingly expanding the above `for` loop does not give any compilation error (the borrow checker likely realizes that the previous `lst` is being shadowed after each line).

```
// Expanding the previous function for v = [0, 1, 2]
let lst = List::Null;
let lst = List::Item(0, Box::new(lst));
let lst = List::Item(1, Box::new(lst));
let lst = List::Item(2, Box::new(lst));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing `let lst = ...` inside the `for` loop, you're creating a new `lst` binding which is immediately dropped after that line. What you want instead is to make the `lst` one level up `mut` and re-assign to that:

```rust
impl<T> List<T> {
    pub fn from_slice(v: &[T]) -> List<T>
    where
        T: Copy,
    {
        let n = v.len();

        let mut lst = List::Null;

        for i in (0..n).rev() {
            lst = List::Item(v[i], Box::new(lst));
        }

        lst
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=adc70dc5d30f2477a318a85ebba82025)